# CSS alignment differs per page, cant find reason

Tags: css

I list products on my homepage and on a company details page.
I use the exact same HTML, but for some reason the product appears different:

The productname is "Artikel 1".

Here the product is displayed correctly: http://www.zorgbeurs.nl/
Notice how the green price area is right below the product.

But here: http://www.zorgbeurs.nl/bedrijven/76/mymedical
the green price area is all the way at the bottom of the page.

Why?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zorgbeurs.nl%2Fbedrijven%2F76%2Fmymedical&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` element is not getting the class assigned because of there is no `ul` element containing it. So the absolute position of the price element is positioned relative to other element ([css positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)).

To get the same final class take into account that styles are inherited from all the parents. Try to enclose the `li` element between `<ul class="product_item">` and `</ul>`.

Comment: Boy, guess I just looked TOO much at it and failed to see it anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the  tag in the mymedical page.

```
<ul class="product_item">
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first link, your `li` element has `position:relative` set, which makes the absolute positioning of the product block work relative to the `li`.  The `li` in the second link does not have relative positioning set, so the absolute positioning rule works relative to the document instead.

As Hamurabi says, this is because the `ul` is missing, and so the rule `.product_item li` no longer applies.